# How to find questions that only have unpopular answers?

Tags: support, search

I've tried several queries, but I found that searching for questions will only allow counting the answers, nothing more.

I like looking for questions without answers (because no competition). I'd really like to find questions that might as well have no answers (because the current ones are so bad).

What can I do to find these questions? I don't know if the search box is good enough to handle this.

If it's a database query (SQL), the result should have links, preferably clickable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this query:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/461118

It'll grab all questions which are not closed, which don't have an accepted answer, and have no answers with a score `>=0`.

Comment: At first I thought that there was only 10 questions like this, and then I looked at the query: any reason why you're limiting it to 10?

Comment: Limiting to 10 because there's no need to pull every single question (there will be hundreds of thousands). You're able to edit/fork the query and modify the limit (maybe 50/100 would be better)? Edit; there are `1,346,000` questions which match the filter, hence the limit :)

Comment: Cool, I think I will. I know a little SQL (well, Google gets me enough SQL that I can put together the queries I want), but I didn't know that I had the ability to make my own queries for SO data.

Comment: Yep - there's a limited subset of information you can query from stackoverflow. You won't get everything, but usually you get *enough*. Also note that this is not querying production data, so the results won't be real time (not sure how often the data is migrated, perhaps daily?)