# Where can I find some interesting JavaScript questions to answer?

Tags: discussion, tags, answers, filtering, tag-filters

I have a lot experience in JavaScript, although now I can hardly keep up with its fast progress, but I do not find many questions that are interesting or worthwhile to answer.

The most common questions that I find, but do not like, are of these types:

- A user uses a library or combination of libraries and gets a strange, library-specific error. Bonus points for questions that include network communication, but do not explain how it's done.
- Manipulating DOM elements with jQuery - those are now simply [help vampire](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) economy stuff and get answered in seconds
- Some basic stuff, like typos, `null`s, using events, using Ajax... This happens in all tags.

I just went to the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag now to see [combination of above mentioned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSZID.png). I'm not saying those questions are poor quality, but for some I'd need to read random library documentation, and for others I'd need the [fastest gun in the west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/209994) since e.g. jQuery problems are often pretty simple.

So, [javascript] followers, could you recommend how I should set up my tag filters so that I can actually help some people?

I like to make experimental fiddles on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). I follow the web workers tags, but most questions there are either about libraries, or about misunderstanding `postMessage` transfer mode.

Comment: This is pretty much *the* problem on Stack Overflow right now. It is not limited to Javascript; it afflicts all tags equally. Experts are tired of answering the same questions over and over again, especially the ones that could be trivially solved by reading the documentation or the compiler's error messages. There is, unfortunately, no good solution to this problem. I wish I could help you, because then I could help myself.

Comment: Yup, pretty much the problem of all high velocity / popular tags. Its more a task of dupe-voting than answering. The only true solution is to not zoom in on the catch-all tag but to specialise. I tend to look at React and Node.JS tagged questions for example, which are better answerable if I had the expertise to do so :)

Comment: @Gimby I started following web workers for this example, as well as node.js. Unfortunatelly, I don't know much more of the popular libraries and environments. I just use raw js in browsers and node.js.

Comment: You can configure your filters to fetch upvoted questions hanging without accepted answer for a few days, combined with a set of whitelisted and blacklisted tags. I was using self-written python script (it used `pystackexchange`) for a while, which emailed me such questions. Not perfect, but worked for me. Though, I used it for `[unix] [posix] [linux]`, not for `[javascript]`.

Comment: Can you give an example of an interesting question? And what do you mean by "experimental fiddles"?

Comment: Maybe in the bounty list...

Comment: @Laurel I enjoyed answering these: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33254303, http://stackoverflow.com/q/10491448, http://stackoverflow.com/q/55677

Comment: You can use the [recommended tab](http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended) and use the advanced filter.

Comment: Are you using the new layout or the old layout? Your available filter functionality will depend on that.

Comment: I think the most interesting questions you will find are the ones that are 1) unanswered and 2) with high score, which aren't many in the first place http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjavascript%5d%20score%3a10%20answers%3a0%20closed%3a0

Comment: Stackoverflow has become the very thing that it was created to solve: yahoo answers.  This happened a long time ago and cannot be fixed.  The horse has bolted on this one.

Comment: Interesting questions are probably as rare as good answers.

Comment: Exactly what @CodyGray said. The python tag is the same way. There's loads of interesting stuff you could do with Python, but if you're not using pandas, scikit-learn, nltk, or just fell off the cabbage truck yesterday and decided to write your first RPG / web scraper / folder reorganizer, you're out of luck finding a question more than once a month.

Comment: @CodyGray The reason why I am not very active on StackOverflow now. And, I think that if this continues, more people will get bored of SO. Ah... If only we could stop it. :(

Comment: [I hear your pain](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333017/can-anyone-suggest-a-good-generic-turn-this-javascript-object-to-this-javascrip/333087#333087)

Comment: I think the help vampire economy is overblown.  To say that it's a deliberate rule-breaking is an oversimplification. Javascript is one of the most popular and easy to get into languages in the world, so there's a ton of beginners and intermediates out there looking for help and looking to help. To mischaracterize their intentions is wrong.

Comment: At least you are not a PHP developer. The questions on that tag are way worse.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment about specializing. Also, there are so many decent (and open source) frameworks available now that you can't really fault people for combining them in new and interesting ways - that's the whole point of innovation. I started trying to answer questions about things I didn't know yet like `angular` and `leaflet` and in the process was motivated to learn those libraries - and now I use them successfully in professional projects. Sometimes you learn more from the niche stuff, even if you don't get a ton of points for it.

Comment: The obvious solution is to burninate `javascript`.  :D On a more serious note, +1 for following more specific tags and specializing a bit in those areas.

Comment: Is your goal to "_actually help some people_" or is it to "_[answer\] interesting or worthwhile [questions]_"?

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica Answering interesting questions also helps people (probably more people than boring questions), what's the point of the question?

Comment: @TomášZato Answering interesting questions _may_ help more people than "boring" questions, but not for sure. If your goal is more to help people, answering "boring" questions achieves that.

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica I don't see your point at all. I have time and patience to answer N qustions per unit of time. Why would focus that time and effort on questions that help less people and are less interesting for me to answer?

Comment: @TomášZato Because you don't know how many people any question will actually help. Just because it's interesting, doesn't mean it will help more people.

Comment: Define interesting

Answer (score 70, accepted):

There's not going to be a perfect filter, so the goal is really to get a search that filters out as much of the bad things as possible.

My suggestion is to use a combination of tags and search operators. Together, it can be very powerful.

### Custom filters and tags

Use custom filters to store a combination of tags you want and tags you don't want. Depending on how broad your tastes are, it may be beneficial to break it down into categories, if possible. I have two main filters that I use: one for questions I may want to edit/close (I have several concurrent burnination crusades happening there) and the other for [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) questions I may want to answer.

There are some really cool sorts and filters available, too. I suggest playing around with it and seeing what works.

When you use a filter, the search box is automatically populated with those tags.

There are a number of different search operators that you may want to use, depending on your tastes. (I looked at your samples of "interesting questions" and I'm still not sure what exactly you mean.)

#### Searching for posts with code

Yes, [it's possible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/331867/6083675), and I probably know the feature the best of anyone here (from extensive experimentation).

There are two limitations that may come up: HTML tags and double quotes; avoid these.

You can search for code using `code:"$()."` to get results containing `$().`, for example.

You can also search for posts that have *any* code using `hascode:1`. It's not as powerful as it could be (due to `inappropriate` backticking), but it still filters a lot out.

#### Searching for questions

You want results for questions (probably), so I would use `is:q`. However, this will return questions that you can't answer, since they're closed or locked. Use `closed:no locked:no` to avoid that.

You can also use `hasaccepted:no` or answers:0 to get questions without an accepted answer or no answers at all respectively. You can get fancy and use `answers:1..1` to get anything with only one answer, while `answers:..3` will get you questions with 3 or fewer answers.

It may also be a good idea to look at the score, too. The very reason we have score on questions is to let the better stuff float to the top. You can also set a maximum score with `score:1..20` meaning score between 1 and 20.

#### Keyword searches

Ultimately, you need to find the right keywords (and know which ones are wrong). While there are those obvious keywords, like "web worker", it's only half the picture.

If you use `web worker` in a search, you will miss any questions that only use the phrase `web workers`. You can use `web worker*` to catch both.

The other important part to keyword searching is to consider the negative side. Learn which words are more often present in "uninteresting" questions and exclude them! Use `-error` to exclude every question that uses the word "error".

There's a specific way that I like to go about making searches. When I see that I'm getting a lot of uninteresting results, I look at one of the first few results and see if I can find a specific term that I feel may be problematic. In your case, you might not be interested in a result that starts with "I'm using the X library...". You could add `-library` to your query. I then search, and repeat the process until I have a manageable amount of results. It's going to filter out a few of the questions you may consider to be interesting, but that's why I experiment with different combinations of filter words.

---

## SEDE

If you need something above and beyond what search has, you need to use SEDE. I'm just going to include the most helpful tricks I know.

#### Searching for phrases

I use `where lower(body) like '% word %'` to find things that include `word`. You can make this a little more robust by using character classes: `'%[> ,.;]word[, .<;]%'`.

There are some really great queries out there if you search around.

I have some that I occasionally use, such as the ["Questions that only have unpopular answers"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319931/6083675) query.

---

In conclusion, you might want to try a search like this:

```
[javascript] -error -problem -library score:3 is:q closed:no locked:no hascode:1
```

If this isn't enough control, you can use SEDE.

Comment: Maybe you'd add -"doesn't work" to the query. Almost all poor questions contain that phrase, in a form or another.

Comment: Is it possible to limit search on the highest score of the answers?

Comment: @Trilarion Only with SEDE. Fortunately, I [asked that question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319931/6083675) months ago and has an answer.

Answer (score 58):

## Everybody vote on questions!

This is the basic mechanism that will allow us to filter out the pearls from the crap. I don't see any way around this solution. Every question page you open, vote on it. Every single one.
Every question you read but don't act upon is a lost one. If it's high quality, never forget to upvote!

Even well explained questions might need to be downvoted for lack of research. Yes, it's harsh, but question downvotes are free already.

Comment: Most of those questions are OK by SO standards. Also my experience is that it already requires a lot of effort to write a question that is accepted positively (or maybe I'm particularly incompetent at it). My problem wasn't "all questions are crap" but "I wanna have fun when answering". That's a different level of standard, all questions can never be fun, programming is a work too.

Comment: I see. However, it's easier to filter good questions for fun than to filter all questions for fun :-) But finding something that is fun *for you* in the search is hard. I guess you can try to find tags (algorithms, functional-programming, whatever) that have a high rate of interesting stuff, but that's always personal.

Comment: @TravisJ: I'm not saying you should only downvote, but that you should vote on every question you read and determined to be good or not. This allows others to recognise junk and quality questions even before having them read.

Comment: It certainly reads like that at present. Shouldn't there be equal guidance? Without upvotes there is no gauge for quality, only for junk.

Comment: I'm way better in recognizing bad questions than good questions...

Comment: @TomášZato *"or maybe I'm particularly incompetent at it"* - heck no, its simple logistics - writing answers of biblical proportions takes up a great deal of time ;)

Comment: @TomášZato Are you saying you don't want to downvote bad questions because it's difficult to write a good one? It's their fault if they don't want to make an effort.

Comment: @Oriol No, I was saying what I said and nothing else. If you don't get it, here's a simplification: The fact that I don't enjoy a question doesn't mean it's bad.

Answer (score 11):

One search query you could use is this:

`[javascript] answers:..0 score:2.. closed:no`

This will search the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag for questions with a score of 2 or more, that also have zero answers so far. From that search you can click the "newest" tab, which will sort by date/time, though it doesn't update live. It will also exclude closed questions.

The need for live updating is lessened a bit, however, by the fact that these are questions which at least two people have found interesting (you can adjust the minimum score to whichever you like) or high quality, and you know they won't likely be trivial answers, since they have zero answers.

Additionally, you can add `-[jquery]` to filter out questions with that tag, or simply `-jquery` to filter out questions that mention the *word* anywhere in their body.

There are currently over 10,400 questions on the site that meet such criteria, so there's no shortage!

Comment: maybe add that you can do `-[jquery]` to get rid of those questions

Comment: I used something similar, but after working my way through the list, I added a date filter to only get newer questions (but not too new, let them sit a day so any trivial ones get answered), because I had answered all the older questions I could find the answers to.

Answer (score 8):

I recently found [Dice Stack](https://www.isimonbrown.co.uk/dicestack/) created by a user named [Gelatin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5551/random-question-button/65975#65975), which gives you a list of random questions from Stack Overflow (or any Stack Exchange site) with optional filters.

You can use this to show, for example, [random questions tagged with javascript, with a question score of 10 or more, and without any answers yet](https://www.isimonbrown.co.uk/dicestack/?site=stackoverflow&min_score=10&tagged=javascript&answer_status=noanswers).

These questions tend to be older, but I use this whenever I'm itching to answer a question but I can't find anything interesting in the newest questions. Get a random list, click a few that look interesting, get another random list, rinse and repeat.

Enjoy that necromancer badge.