# Can anyone suggest a good generic "turn this JavaScript object to this JavaScript object" question for duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, canonical

Basically I'm a bit fed up of questions along the lines of

> Here's a JavaScript/JSON object I need to be this similar but slightly
>   different JavaScript/JSON object. Please can someone do this for me?

There is no real answer to these as they're all subtly different, nor are they any use to anybody in the future, because every answer is unique to the situation. So I feel a good canonical answer would be in order (I don't have the time or inclination to do this).

Can anyone advise what we can do about this and/or produce or suggest a good canonical *"this is roughly how you do this"* kind of Q&A so that these can be marked as a duplicate?

At the moment I mostly close as *"too broad"*. Maybe this is the best thing to do?

Examples:

- [How to filter a nested data structure in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39103106/filter-json-in-javascript)
- [Transform JSON Object to another - Format
  It](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9016546/transform-json-object-to-another-format-it)
- [Iterating Nested JSON to array of objects
  (JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958544/iterating-nested-json-to-array-of-objects-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [How to sort JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39077551/how-to-sort-json)
- etc., etc., etc.

Anyone who spends any time looking though JavaScript questions will see many of these every day.

Comment: Would you mind providing links to a few example questions? (Not asking you to answer your own question, but just a few so we're sure we know what you're talking about.)

Comment: I was trying not to generate the "meta effect" but if you insist!

Comment: 90% of the time, it's not even JSON, for some reason JSON and a Javascript object are used interchangeably all the time, but well that's a different irritation

Comment: Seems like a good candidate for Stack Overflow documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation

Comment: I still feel like the questions would need closing. I couldn't point them as documentation as a duplicate? Though this is a good point

Comment: I usually CV these as a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

Comment: Thta's a good one @Teemu. I've made a note

Comment: Is there already a good "How do I tell JSON and JavaScript objects apart" question? Then we could use a comment to point there and close as "unclear what asking". I also find the "recommend a [...] tutorial" close reason more and more appealing if there's not a basic understanding.

Comment: There's this [Javascript object Vs JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294088/javascript-object-vs-json) @ThomasWeller though I think it could do with some improvements

Comment: Problem is that question has the right title but the question itself is very specific. It doesn't really highlight all the differences between JSON and JS objects

Comment: @Thomas: How about http://stackoverflow.com/q/2904131/218196 ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The majority of these questions--and there are many of them, and they are annoying, and they are hard to figure out why to CV--are by utter beginners, many of whom don't know the difference between an object and an array, JSON and a JavaScript object, or how to access a property on an object, and can barely write a for loop, much less a `.map`, and generally also have no clue how to debug their programs, if they ever write one themselves.

What these people really need to do is quit programming for a while and do what we wise old-timers did, which is to study, research, learn, and read. There's plenty of stuff out there. It's not hard to find. There's a mental barrier--they don't understand the **need** to study. For some, SO is like crack cocaine that gives them that instant high, a magic, real-time code writing service.

Many of these questions specify the use of underscore or lodash, which is fine, but it seems to never have occurred to the poster, or they are too lazy, to just do a CTRL-F on the underscore page to search for "merge" or whatever.

I've never figured out what reason to give for closing these, so I usually just downvote, sometimes even breaking my personal rule not to downvote folks with single-digit reps.

Comment: That's why I like the "recommend a [...] tutorial" close reason.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think this is a good fit for a canonical post. The scenario of converting one JavaScript object into another varies greatly and is often a custom solution. This is evident in your linked examples, where a combination of either `map`, `filter`, or a recursive projection is required.

It is better in these scenarios for the user to first attempt to create the custom implementation, and then post their attempt if it is unsuccessful for some reason.

That said, creating a canonical question isn't going to cause any harm by having it around, so long as it isn't used for inappropriate closure of XY type problems.

Comment: Yes, but what to do with the questions where the user didn't attempt anything? Closing as "too broad", "unclear what you're asking" or "if you seek debugging help…" doesn't always fit.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion such questions should be closed as a duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/3853934) (linked [in comments by Teemu](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333017/can-anyone-suggest-a-good-generic-turn-this-javascript-object-to-this-javascrip#comment386907_333017)). Felix Kling's answer explains the basics of processing objects in JavaScript, and I also posted [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40195701/3853934) which focuses on using built-in methods of arrays and objects.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps multiple canonical questions of the format:

> How do I convert an array of X to an array of Y?

...or

> How do I merge the contents of an array to a single value?

...could go over the basics of `.map` or `.reduce`. That could potentially let us close an enormous number of questions as duplicates. I'm not sure if that would enlighten or confuse, but my hope would be that people would start to think through their problems in smaller, more understandable pieces.